# How do you add a reserved word to your Javascript development environment?

Tags: javascript, utility, reserved-words

For tasks that are done very often, e.g. `console.log`, I would like to create a reserved word.

Yes, I could create a `utility function`, but then I'd have to import it into every file where I would like to call it.

When I say reserved word, I mean the same way that `debugger` is a reserved word.

**How would you create a custom reserved word in javascript?**

Comment: Rewrite V8 or any other engine.

Comment: I am also thinking it is changing something core - but wondering if there is a simpler way than rewriting the entire engine :)

Comment: As Jonas mentioned, there isn't really any support for that short of rewriting something in the engine itself. This may be an XY problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: You could use a getter inside of a `with` statement to get a behaviour like the `debugger` statement, but thats still far away from any real world usage.

Comment: I run a snipplet when I need to run code, seems like an easy thing to do....

Comment: Just shorthand things that you do very often. I do a lot of work in React so having console.log, this.props, and this.state as cl(tp, ts) would be awesome.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean by snipplet?

Comment: Aha ... So you just want to add some shortcuts to your editor? Thats probably way easier then a "reserved word"

Comment: You use a transpiler or something like https://www.sweetjs.org/. You wouldn't be able to still call the resulting language "JavaScript", though.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/predefined-snippets

Comment: @JonasW. I wanted the entire team to be able to use this, and maybe the community at large if others found it useful. If it's possible to write a little npm module that would hook into webpack somehow and allow it's use without having to import it into every file you're working in, that would be amazing. Or maybe an atom plugin.

Comment: what about something like creating your own emmet actions: https://docs.emmet.io/customization/

Comment: @ardev I'll take a look at emmet.